# Converting decimal to binary without arrays

Tags: c

Question: Write a program that converts decimal to binary number without using arrays

What I have done is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int rem,n,rev=0; 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n>0) {
        rem=n%2;
        n=n/2;
        printf("%d",rem);
    }
}
```

In while loop when `n` is `>0` I have stored remainder in `rem` variable and `n/=2` and `printf rem`

Now ahead I want to reverse the `rem`  so I have used normal approach to reverse a number but the zeros are not coming what to do?

Like 
Input:4
Output should be:0010
output is coming:1
Input:8
Output should be:1000
output is 1
Like this

Comment: #include<stdio.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>  
int main()
{  
        int rem,n,rev=0;
       scanf("%d",&n);
        while(n>0)
        {
            rem=n%2;
            n=n/2;
            printf("%d",rem);
            }
            
           }

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the code and format it properly (there is a help section in the editor).

Comment: Recursion is one way to print the value in the correct order.

Comment: "I have used normal approach to reverse a number" - what's this "normal approach", exactly? Please post your full code

Comment: What do you mean "the zeros are not coming"? Please give the exact input, desired output and actual output. For the zero case just add a special condition at the start: `if (n==0) { printf("0"); return; }`

Comment: Also, can you please update the title of the question? Currently it doesn't describe the problem at all.

Comment: Your original title conveyed no information about what you're trying to do. You want to use a title that will catch the attention of readers who are interested in and knowledgeable about what you're asking.

Comment: You've already violated the "no arrays" constraint by using a string literal. The question as posed is nonsensical.

Comment: Wait I will update the question

Answer (score 1):

The following illustrates two methods, iterative and recursive:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void printBinaryIterative(uint32_t num)
{
    uint32_t bit = 0x80000000;

    while(bit)
    {
        if(bit & num)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");

        bit >>= 1;
    }
}

void printBinaryRecursive(uint32_t num)
{
    if(num / 2)
        printBinaryRecursive(num / 2);

    printf("%u", num % 2);
}

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t num;

    printf("Iterative\n");
    num = 0x00000001;
    printf("0x%08X = ", num);
    printBinaryIterative(num);
    printf("\n");

    num = 0x80000000;
    printf("0x%08X = ", num);
    printBinaryIterative(num);
    printf("\n");

    num = 0x5CA1AB1E;
    printf("0x%08X = ", num);
    printBinaryIterative(num);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Recursive\n");
    num = 0x00000001;
    printf("0x%08X = ", num);
    printBinaryRecursive(num);
    printf("\n");

    num = 0x80000000;
    printf("0x%08X = ", num);
    printBinaryRecursive(num);
    printf("\n");

    num = 0x5CA1AB1E;
    printf("0x%08X = ", num);
    printBinaryRecursive(num);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The following output is produced:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main.exe; ./main.exe;
Iterative
0x00000001 = 00000000000000000000000000000001
0x80000000 = 10000000000000000000000000000000
0x5CA1AB1E = 01011100101000011010101100011110
Recursive
0x00000001 = 1
0x80000000 = 10000000000000000000000000000000
0x5CA1AB1E = 1011100101000011010101100011110
```

Comment: I think I'd like this  decent answer better with more explanation.

Comment: In the recursive version using the same `>> 1` notation might be more consistent.